# Entity Framework and include

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a edmx model of the aspnet login account holders tables.

Entityframework removes the AspNetUserRoles table and display a relationship directly between AspNetRole and the AspNetUser tables

The question I have is how or what is the best why to get a list of AspNetUser in a certain role role?

```
Public Function getAccountHoldersInRoles(role As String) As IEnumerable(Of AspNetUser)

    Dim aspNetUsers = From u In db.AspNetUsers.Include("AspNetRoles")

    For Each u In aspNetUsers

           ??????????????

    Next


    Return aspNetUsers
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Include` unless you have some case where you need the data after the context is disposed.

If Users and Roles have a many-to-many relationship then this is what you need.

C#

```
var usersInRole = db.AspNetUsers.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleName == role));
```

VB

```
Dim usersInRole = db.AspNetUsers.Where(Function(u) u.Roles.Any(Function(r) r.RoleName = role))
```